# Iterative training using VowpalWabbit

Tags: vowpalwabbit

I am trying to perform iterative testing using VW.

Ideally I would be able to:

1. Train and save a model initial_model.vw (I have tested this and it works)
2. Load this model, add additional data to it, and save it again (to new_model.vw)
3. Use this new model to make predictions that the first model was not able to make to prove the iterative training has been successful.

I found one person also trying to do this ([how to retrain the model for sequence of files in vowpal wabbit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27186351/how-to-retrain-the-model-for-sequence-of-files-in-vowpal-wabbit)) but when I run my code and try to retrain with additional data, it seems to overwrite the old data instead of adding to it.

Here is the basic outline of the code I am using:

1. Initial training and saving:

```
    vw initial_data.txt -b 26 --learning_rate 1.5 --passes 10 -- 
    probabilities --loss_function=logistic --oaa 80 --save_resume --kill_cache 
    --cache_file a.cache -f initial_model.vw
```

2. Retraining with new data:

```
    vw new_data.txt -b 26 --learning_rate 1.5 -- 
    passes 10 -i initial_model.vw --probabilities --loss_function=logistic -- 
    oaa 80 --save_resume --kill_cache --cache_file a.cache -f new_model.vw
```

I know that this is not enough to reproduce what I am doing but I just want to know if there are any problems with my arguments and if this should be working in theory. When I use my retrained model to make predictions, it is only accurate for test cases which are included in the new data, not anything that was covered in the original training file. Help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I can see 2 *potential* issues with the arguments given in the question.
These may be ok, if you actually meant to use them this way, and you really know what you're doing, but they seem a bit suspect.

1) Whenever you run `vw` with multiple passes over the same data (`--passes <n>`), `vw` implicitly switches to hold-out mode with a 1 in 10 examples, held-out. Held-out examples are used only for error estimation, and not for learning to avoid over-fitting. If this is what you meant to do, then fine, but if you don't want to hold-out any of your examples, you should use the option `--holdout_off`, and be aware that the chances of over-fitting are increased.

2) The initial learning rate (`--learning_rate 1.5`) seems high, it increases over-fitting chances. If you use it because you end up with a lower training-loss, this is the wrong thing to do. in ML the goal is not to minimize training-loss but generalization loss.

Also: setting the initial learning-rate on the 2nd batch seems to contradict the `--save_resume` option.  The goal of `--save_resume` is to start an new batch with low (already decayed, as saved in the model) per-feature learning rates (AdaGrad style). Making the learning rate jump at the start may make the first examples in the 2nd batch much more important than all the decayed features from the 1st batch.

Tip: you can get a feel of how well you're doing, by piping the progress output into the plotting utility `vw-convergence`:

```
 vw -P 1.1 ... data.txt 2>&1 | vw-convergence
```

(note: vw-convergence requires `R`)